# Fullcalendar databind from database in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, entity-framework-4.1, fullcalendar

I'm going to use [Fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) in my asp.net web forms application. I need to bind data to calendar using database.

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you have to write a web service which will return json string of events containing attributes like title , start, end, allDay. 
See Event Object doc [Event_Object](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)

Then use events as a json feed to fetch event objects. [events_json_feed](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/)